# Pexpect: Can't Write to STDIN — Why?

Tags: python, pexpect

Why doesn't this work?

```py
data, status = run('grep o', stdout=True, stdin='lol')
print(f'data: {data}, status: {status}')
```

Full code:

```py
import pexpect
import sys
def run(cmd, prompts=[], password=None, stdout=False, stdin=''):
    """runs and interacts with external commands"""
    child = pexpect.spawn(cmd, encoding='utf-8')
    for prompt in prompts:
        try:
            child.expect(prompt)
        except pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT:
            print(f'prompt "{prompt}" not matched')
            sys.exit(1)
        child.sendline(password)
    child.send(stdin)
    try:
        data = child.read() if stdout else None
    except pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT:
        print('command took too long to print to stdout')
        sys.exit(1)
    child.close()
    return data, child.exitstatus

data, status = run('grep o', stdout=True, stdin='lol')
print(f'data: {data}, status: {status}')
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```py
def run(cmd, prompts=[], password=None, stdout=False, stdin=None):
    """runs and interacts with external commands"""
    child = pexpect.spawn(cmd, encoding='utf-8')
    for prompt in prompts:
        try:
            child.expect_exact(prompt)
        except pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT:
            err(f'prompt "{prompt}" not matched')
        child.sendline(password)
    if stdin is not None:
        child.sendline(stdin)
        child.sendeof()
        child.sendeof()
    try:
        data = child.read() if stdout else None
    except pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT:
        err('command took too long to print to stdout')
    exitstatus = child.wait()
    return data, exitstatus
```

Differences:

- `child.send(stdin)` -> `child.sendline(stdin)`
- `child.sendeof()` is repeated twice.  This is not required for this
  specific example (i.e. running `grep o`), but apparently necessary for
  `scrypt enc - out.enc`.  I don't know why tho.

I don't know why any of the above works.  If you know let me know.

Not that it matters, but I'm using function `err` instead of `print` and `sys.exit`:

```
def err(msg):
    sys.stderr.write('{ERR}*{CLR} {}\n'.format(msg, **THEME))
    sys.stderr.flush()
```